# jQuery animation doesn´t work on opera mini

Tags: jquery, opera

please test an jquery fadein/out animation click event on opera mini. You will see that the opera mini can not understand the animation and will let the opacity for example at 0.5.
Does somebody know how to fix this bug?

Comment: Opera Mini has *very* limited support for JavaScript animation, it's not a bug, it's a feature.

Answer (score 1):

Support for javascript is limited on opera mini. It is classified as 'b' grade supported by jQuery.

Further reading: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-web-content-authoring-guidelines/#javascript

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. In my opinion it doesn´t make sense than to use jQuery feautures on opera mini. So I´ll write an exeption that if the client uses opera mini all will be static.
There are two things I´d like to know:
1.) What the hell there are thinking with such a concept? Why someone ever invented something?
2.) Are there more browsers which are rendering the code like opera mini?

Comment: You need to go back a few years. The world before iPhone. Back then most of the browsing on mobile devices was done on the so called 'wap' sites which were arguably in their infancy. The devices were low powered and browsers like opera mine etc. had slow javascript engines and no hardware acceleration. It made perfect sense to do that back then. I am not sure of the usage share but I think you could probably skip worrying about targeting those devices.

Comment: I think about to check the user agent and if it match opera mini than all the fadeIn and FadeOut effects will go with a speed of 0.